# How to get Assets to remember last folder in file chooser?

Tags: assets

In Assets for ExpressionEngine the file chooser will remember the folder from which an image was last selected, even if picking images from across instances of Assets fields in different Matrix rows. It saves a lot of time when populating large galleries such as in a photographic portfolio.

The same thing doesn't seem to be true of Assets in Craft though - each time I open the file chooser, unless it's the same Assets field I'm adding to or replacing into, I have to go from the root folder and find the correct sub-folder again.

I guess I'm hoping there's a nifty config item somewhere which will set 'remember last folder' to true...?

Comment: Update from Brandon over on the Craft Google group suggests this feature will return later in 2015. https://plus.google.com/100799487544987844687/posts/KNFYCasJeG8?cfem=1